# What is the exact difference between a chazakah and a rov?

Tags: halacha, lomdus, chazaka

I was asked this question by a friend of mine and at first I thought it was so simple (and maybe it is, maybe I just don’t have enough Torah knowledge to know the answer) but when I tried to explain the difference, I kept getting caught by my friend saying, that’s the same thing as a rov/chazakah. They are both halachically accepted forms of assumptions based on the probability that a certain outcome will repeat itself.

Comment: Chazaka is a way in a situation of safek. Rov is a solution for a safek

Comment: Rov and chazakah can each to refer to a number of different concepts, some more similar to each other than others. Consider clarifying (maybe with examples) which types of rov and chazakah you're referring to here

Comment: Traditionally explained in yeshiva lomdus as *psak*/*hanhaga* vs *birur* ...

Answer (score 13):

There are many types of *chazakos* and *rovs*, so it's good to define our terms before  we compare them. What both of them have in common is they tend to address *sefeikos*, or uncertainties.

**Chazaka D'MeIkara חזקה דמעיקרא**

Basically, assume what was, will be. For example: חזקת כשרות, חזקת פנויה, חזקת אשת איש, חזקת איסור, or in English: something is still kosher, someone is still single, someone is still married, something is still forbidden. Even if you see that something has changed, you assume it changed at the last possible moment. While assuming things don't change could be logical (status quo), this latter novelty is not logical. It is a decree of the writ, a גזרת הכתוב. See **Chullin 10b** for the source and discussion on this type of *chazaka*.

**Chezkas HaGuf חזקת הגוף**

Similar to חזקה דמעיקרא, basically put it's the assumption that something physical hasn't changed. See **Kesubos** 12b for an example. Some say that this is stronger that a typical חזקה דמעיקרא (see **Shev Shemaatesa** 1:15).

**Chezkas Mammon חזקת ממון**

The *gemarra* (**Bava Kamma** 46b) calls this logical, to the point that you don't even need a source for it. Essentially it's the assumption that your possessions are yours until proven otherwise.

**Behavioral Chazakos חזקה אדם וגו'‏**

This is the assumption that people usually act a certain way. For example חזקה אין אדם עושה סעודה ומפסידה, we assume a person won't make a wedding feast only to ruin his marriage the next day (**Kesubos** 10a). חזקה אין אשה מעיזה פניה בפני בעלה, a woman wouldn't brazenly lie in front of her husband that he divorced her (**Gittin** 64b). More on this below.

**Chezkas Gimmel Pa'amim חזקת ג' פעמים**

We assume something that happened three times will continue to happen (שור המועד (**Exodus** 21:29), קטלנית (**Yevamos** 64b)).

**Soklin al HaChazakos סוקלין על החזקות**

Something that we assumed was true due to some proof (a single witness (see **Mishneh Torah** *Hilchos Sanhedrin* 16:6), logic), we will use even to execute punishments. For example, a new couple comes to town with two children. They act as a family, so we assume they're all related. If they commit incest together, they are punished based off that *chazaka* (**Kiddushin** 80a).

---

The *gemarra* in **Chullin** 11a teaches that there are two types of *rov*:

**Ruba DeIsa Kaman רובא דאיתא קמן**

A *rov* where the majority is before us. The classic example is 9 stores in town sell kosher meat and one sells non-kosher, and you find a piece of meat. *Rov* tells you to assume this piece of meat came from the majority.

**Ruba DeLeisa Kaman רובא דליתא קמן**

A *rov* where the majority isn't before us. There are different ways to define this. One way is this *rov* isn't known with cold-hard facts, it's just something that is generally known to be true (see **Kovetz Shiurim** I *Bava Basra* § 83, see there further for other explanations). For example, most animals are not born with a life-threatening blemish or illness. Or most people are not born infertile.

There are also different applications of *rov*. The above are referred to as **Heilach achar HaRov**, following the majority. Another application is **Bittul BeRov**, where in a mixture the minority becomes nullified and is considered like the majority.

---

Now, coming back to your question. I'm not sure which *chazakos* and *rovs* you and your friend were discussing, but my assumption is **Behavioral Chazakos** and **Ruba DeLeisa Kaman**. These work very similarly, since another way to phrase "there's a *chazaka* that a person would/not do X" as "most people do/don't do X". As noted by @JoelK, there are those that explicitly equate the two. **Rav Asher Weiss** in **Minchas Asher** *Vayikra* § 25 provides a proof that this is true. **Chullin** 11b suggests a source for **Ruba DeLeisa Kaman** is the fact that someone who bruises their father is sentenced to death, even though it's not known for sure who their father is. Rather, it's because *rov beilos achar haba'al*, even if the mother was unfaithful, most of the time she is with her husband. We therefore assume she became pregnant from him. The *gemarra* calls this a *rov*, yet the **Yerushalmi Kiddushin** 4:10 explains this case is the source for *chazaka*. Seemingly it's referring to **Behavioral Chazakos**, and thus the terms *chazaka* and *rov* in this context are interchangeable. See also **Kiddushin** 80a, which seems to call a *rov* a *chazaka* at the same time.

Not so other *chazakos* and *rovs*. You're right they both are assumptions that solve uncertainties, but they work differently, and they have different rules and laws. Some want to say that a **Chazaka D'MeIkara** doesn't answer the question, just tells you how to act, while **Rov** answers your uncertainty (see [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%97%D7%95%D7%96%D7%A7_%D7%94%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA#cite_ref-2) for some sources). There's a rule that *rov* is stronger than certain *chazakos* (**Niddah** 18a), yet *rov* doesn't beat **Chezkas Mammon** (**Bava Kamma** 27b). They're not interchangeable or equatable. As well, clearly **Bittul BeRov** is different than *chazakos*.

Answer (score 6):

There are indeed opinions which essentially understand certain forms of *chazakah* as a *rov*.

For example, R. Yisrael Isserlein writes in [Terumat HaDeshen 207](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1835&st=&pgnum=66&hilite=):

> חזקה שאינה פוסקת **שהיא באה מכח הרוב** כמו החזקה אין עדים חתומים על השטר אא"כ נעשה גדול וכן חזקה אין אדם פורע בגו זמנו וחזקה שאין אדם עושה בעילת בעילת זנות דכל הני חזקות **באים מן הרוב כלומר רוב בני אדם אין עושים אלא בענין זה** אפילו בדיני נפשות סמכינן אחזקה כה"ג‏
>
> A *chazakah*  which does not cease, **which comes from the power of *rov***, such as the *chazakah* that witnesses do not sign a document if they are underage, or the *chazakah* that a person does not repay a debt early, or the *chazakah* that a person will not make his act of sexual intercourse into an improper one, all these *chazakot* **come from the power of *rov* i.e. most people only act in this way**. We rely on such a *chazakah* even in capital cases.

R. Shimon Shkop in [Sha'arei Yosher 3:3](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53353&st=&pgnum=54&hilite=) distinguishes between a *chazakah* solely based on statistics (such as the *chazakah* that a woman will not falsely claim to her husband's face that he has divorced her) and a *chazakah* that is based on both statistics and a certain internal logic (such as the *chazakah* that people do not repay debts early).

He understands, based on the principle of *ein holchin bemamon achar harov*, that the former kind of *chazakah* cannot be used to extract money from a defendant, suggesting that this kind of *chazakah* is indistinguishable from *rov*. However, the latter kind of *chazakah* is strong enough to extract money; a *chazakah* based on logic as well as statistics is stronger than one based on statistics alone.

Another way to look at these types of *chazakot* in a way that is different from *rov*, is to understand them as discussing the way we perceive the world, rather than performing a statistical analysis.

For instance, R. Moshe Sofer in his [Responsa Chatam Sofer Choshen Mishpat 67](https://www.sefaria.org/Responsa_Chatam_Sofer%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.67?lang=bi) writes of the *chazakah* that a debt is not repaid early that it is 'as if we are witnesses' (*anan sahadi*) that such is the case, and that such a *chazakah* can therefore be used to extract money. Similarly, R. Aryeh Leib HaKohen Heller in [Shev Shmat'ta 6:22](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%90/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%95/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%9B%D7%91) writes that this *chazakah* is based on logic (*sevara*) and is thus stronger than *rov*.

The way I understand their approaches (although I grant that this is not necessarily the only way to read them) is that a *chazakah*, while it might be ultimately be based on a statistical phenomenon, takes on a life of its own when (for whatever reason) it becomes a feature of how people view the world. This is in distinction to a pure *rov* (such as the majority of animals do not have a fatal illness) where we are not coming in with any prior assumptions, and it is the questions that are asked which require us to perform a statistical analysis in order to come up with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go through the whole topic right now, and whatever I can say will be in contention. Rov is separated into 2 separate categories, one of which is based upon a פסוק in the Torah, אחרי הרבים להטות. This rov is called רובא דאיתא קמן and is based upon the majority of the current possibilities before us. What is considered 'before us' is a subject of debate. This is not a logical statistical conclusion. The רש"ש on בבא בתרא (צג:) brings down an argument in the פוסקים if in the classical case of תשעה חנויות (9 stores sells kosher and one sells non-kosher) what if the one large non-kosher store sells more meat per day than the other 9 kosher stores. Do we go based upon the number of stores or the volume of meat. This is a seemingly obvious question, as statistically the volume of meat is what determines the probability. But the question is if רובא דאיתא קמן looks at the amount of meat or the number of stores. This is to prove that רובא דליתא קמן is not statistics.
חזקה, as Robev explained earlier, is not one thing. There are many different types of חזקות, the most common of which is חזקה דמעיקרא. This is also based upon a פסוק and is not statistical. An example is if I have two knives, one of which is kosher for שחיטה and one of which is not, and I grab one of them and use it to perform שחיטה. Afterwards I realize that I don't know which knife I use. חזקה makes the cow not kosher. This is again illogical, as there is nothing that says that since the cow was not kosher before, therefore I picked up knife a instead of knife b. This type of חזקה is called a הנהגה, a halachik tool that says when in doubt pick me.
רובא דאיתא קמן is the most statistical of the bunch. It says that being that most people do x, or nature dictates y, they are more likely to be true. This type of rov is called a בירור by some, and actually establishes how we should look at the reality, not just a when in doubt do... sort of thing. I wrote a paper on this a while back if you're interested.

Answer (score -2):

The terms can be used in slightly different ways (much as in the same way that the definition of "fact" changes when you compare it to "fiction" or "opinion") but one way to understand it is as follows:

A Chazaka has more depth because it inherently requires more "time" depth, more data points, to draw a conclusion.

Examples:

A Rov:

The dice has four red sides and two green sides. If we don't remember the roll, we presume a red came up.

A Chazaka.

After 100 throws, the dice came up red 66 times. We presume the dice has four red sides and two green sides and then presume that an an additional unrecorded roll was red.

Comment: What about רובא דליתא קמן? Eg רוב בהמות כשרות. That seems more similar to how you have defined chazaka

Answer (score -2):

Both are usually associated with assumptions and clarifications in areas we lack certainty . The difference between them is what the assumption is based on.

Rov means majority. The assumption is being based on the statistical likelihood.

Additionally, a Rov/majority can influence the status of the minority in Halacha. For example, if a small amount of non-kosher food  falls into a large amount of kosher the rov/majority of koshr food can make everything koher (ask your LOR before relying on this in a practical case)

Chazaka is simply an assumption. Based on the information we have and the way the world works we can assume something. It usually upholds the status quo until we have more information

A Rov is a stronger type of assumption than Chazaka and if they are contradicting each other the Rov would usually override the Chazaka

Comment: You seem to be contrasting רובא דאיתא קמן with חזקה דמעיקרה. What about רובא דליתא קמן? What about a חזקה such as חזקה שליח עושה שליחותו?

Comment: I used the terms "usually" because there are too many types of chazokos to discuss them all in the answer here." the way the world works we can assume something"  is a reference to chazokos that are based on Umdina

Comment: If you're talking about umdina then this sentence "It usually upholds the status quo until we have more information" is a little misleading - consider חזקה אין אדם פורע חובו תוך זמנו which can be used להוציא ממון

Comment: Also, it's not at all clear that we apply רובא וחזקה רובא עדיף to a case of אומדנא